# Replace SVN trunk with brand new version

Tags: svn, branch, trunk

I'm working on a branch of a mobile application where:

- The platform has changed from Windows Mobile 8.1 to UWP
- Libraries have been updated to UWP versions
- Various code changes related to the library updates have been done

We are now ready to make this new branch (named UWP2) the new trunk, whilst retaining the old code in order to support clients still having the old version. We would also like to retain the history of the trunk. I think it should be done like:

1. Branch current trunk to a new branch, called *trunk-old*, or something. I know how to do this part.
2. Delete the files in trunk (svn delete trunk)
3. Copy the UWP2 branch onto trunk (svn copy UWP2 trunk)

My question is: **will these commands accomplish all our goals?**